# VirtualBox internal network will allow ping and traceroute but not nc

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing, tcp, traceroute

**Update**: `tcpdump` shows only ARP traffic with `nc` generating ARP traffic `who has 192.168.254 tell 192.168.1.64` but `tracepath` says tell Fedora who has 192.168.1.5. 192.168.1.5 is pingable but 264 is not. Fedora is the host where I am doing the `ping`.

I have put a Fedora 39 and a Bitnami PostgreSQL 15 (15.5.0-r3) on Debian 11 on an internet.

`traceroute -T`, `tracepath` and `ping` will find the PostgreSQL host but `nc` won't eg:

> Ncat: no route to host.

So what gives?

**Note**: All but `ping` will have `-p 1531` appended after the address. Yes the port number is `5432`. Man page says `nc` defaults to TCP.

Comment: No. The fedora has 2 nic's but 1st is a nat open to internet

Comment: I don't see why they would allow up to 4 nic's if they could not support parallel use.